# Check authorization for each request in django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app setup as follows:

```
MyApp
    CustomAdmin
        urls
        models
        views
    MainApp
        settings
        urls
        wsgi
    SomeOtherApp
        admin
        models
        views
```

Now, in my `MainApp.urls`, I've setup a the following url:

```
url(r'^api/admin/', include('CustomAdmin.urls')),
```

In `CustomAdmin`, I want to have a single mechanism where it checks if the request, regardless of the associated view, is being made by a `superuser` or not. If it is made by a superuser, the request should be processed by the associated view function else it should throw a 403 or similar error.

I've used something similar in Laravel as follows

```
Route::group(
    array(
        'before' => 'auth.admin',
        'prefix' => 'api/admin'        
        ),
    function(){
        ....
    });
```

I'm not sure if such a mechanism exists in Django. If there is, what should I be doing?

Comment: I think you need a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process_request). This could be also useful [request and respons docs from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) that will allow you to do some work on the request before processing it in the views. In a file called `middleware.py`, put:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login

class AllowSuperUserOnly(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/api/admin/'):
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
                return redirect_to_login(request.path)
        # Continue processing the request as usual:
        return None
```

And add the middleware to your `settings.py`. It should look similar to this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'your_app.middleware.AllowSuperUserOnly',
)
```

Comment: in recent versions of Django (2+) must be replaced by `AllowSuperUserOnly(MiddlewareMixin)` and add `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to define it on the url pattern that includes the others (will test a bit more about that later), but it is at least possible in `CustomAdmin.urls` by using the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator.

```
# CustomAdmin/urls.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from CustomAdmin import views

requires_superuser = user_passes_test(lambda x: x.is_superuser)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(  # with a class based view
        r'^$', 
        requires_superuser(views.SomeView.as_view()), 
        name='someview'
    ),
    url(  # with a functional view
        r'^(?P<foo>\w+)/$', 
        requires_superuser(views.someotherview),    
        name='someotherview'
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.base/View/) and from [Django Class-bases views docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#view), `dispatch()` is the first method called in a class-bases view.

View class workflow

1. dispatch()
2. http_method_not_allowed()
3. options()

**Keep in mind than all generic views inherits View class**

Middleware is a good solution, but if you do not need to pre-process *every request* you could use an **access mixin**.

As I said before, `dispatch()` is the first executed method, so you can re write it to grant or deny access to a view.

Here is `dispatch` default code:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
    # request method isn't on the approved list.
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can write a `mixin` class:

```
class SuperuserRequiredMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin allows you to require a user with `is_superuser` set to True.
    """

    login_url = settings.LOGIN_URL  # LOGIN_URL from project settings
    raise_exception = False  # Default whether to raise an exception to none
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME  # Set by django.contrib.auth

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:  # If the user is a standard user,
            if self.raise_exception:  # *and* if an exception was desired
                return HttpResponseForbidden()  # return a forbidden response.
            else:
                # otherwise, redirect the user to the login page.
                # Also, handily, sets the `next` GET argument for
                # future redirects.
                path = urlquote(request.get_full_path())
                tup = self.login_url, self.redirect_field_name, path
                return HttpResponseRedirect("%s?%s=%s" % tup)

        return super(SuperuserRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can use it in your views. Let's suppose a `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from somewhere import SuperuserRequiredMixin

class MyView(ListView, SuperuserRequiredMixin):
    ...
    # Do what you usually do...
```

I hope you find this useful.